# How do I force Firefox to check for a new version of page (browser.cache.check_doc_frequency doesn't work)?

Tags: firefox

When I go to, for example, reddit.com ... the page doesn't automatically show the new content or update my message indicator. I have to manually refresh every time. This is using firefox 3.6.16 on windows 7. I have set the browser.cache.check_doc_frequency setting to 1, and it still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I use Reddit frequently and I've never had that problem. Any time you click to a subreddit or back to the main page it should load the latest material (including messages).

Comment: yup, that works too. If I could get the latest version without clicking anything, that'd be nice. I'm at a loss. The only odd plugin I have running is stylish, which shouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized later what's going on. If I close the browser with tabs open, and then reopen the browser so that it reloads those tabs automatically... the tabs don't all get auto-refreshed. So I was viewing e.g. unrefreshed reddit. If I open a new tab, or close all tabs and then visit the page... it loads the freshest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a fluke, as recent visits to the page show it freshly every time. It may have something to do with firefox quitting in a nonstandard way... I use mouse shortcuts that will quit it using either ctrl+W or alt+F4. Maybe one of those doesn't quit properly or cause it to check for an updated version next time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're having your reddit problem, but to actually answer your question:

You can force Firefox to update any page (and ignore the cache settings) by using **CTRL + F5** to refresh the page, instead of just **F5**.