# Auto-refresh when loading tab from last session

Tags: firefox, browser-cache, session, browser-tabs, refresh

Assume I opened several questions from StackOverflow (but actually problem is with any StackExchange site). While researching problem, some questions/answers was helpful so I upvoted them, after that I closed Firefox to continue work later.

The next time I open Firefox, it restore all previous opened tabs (but not load any tab until I click it). But when I load tabs with question that was upvoted by me earlier - this questions look like they was *before* my voting - just like if I wasn't upvote them. If I open this questions in new tabs - they are up to date.

I guess this is because Firefox just load page from cache, while voting is javascript "runtime" action that does not change cache. It can explain why manual refresh actually update page (my upvotes appears), while `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` doesn't resolve issue. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/276737/how-do-i-force-firefox-to-check-for-a-new-version-of-page-browser-cache-check-d) is question with exactly the same problem (example for different site but it doesn't matter I guess), but there is not answer how to resolve this issue.

How to force Firefox to autorefresh tabs from previous session when loading this tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you are looking for perhaps but a hands-free solution nevertheless:

1. Install extension [Tab Rotator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-rotator/)
2. In the Tab Rotator Settings-Page the time interval after which the next tab should be shown, can by set to 1 second (more if needed).
3. When Firefox is restored the extension will switch between all the tabs and consequently each one of them will be loaded

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I usually have over 100 tabs and really don't want to load them all :)

Comment: welcome to superuser.com. Your answer gives a possible solution, so no worries! (even though the OP may need something closer to his specific needs, this answer can still help other people with the same problem). +1 from me.